# How do I test my interface functions?

Tags: unit-testing, go

Third day in Go so pardon if this is a newb question ;). I am creating a simple calculator that will eventually have many different tasks: addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc, etc...Each of the tasks will have 2 functions: First and Second.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/mytestproj/calculator"
)

type Calc interface {
    First(x int) int
    Second(x int) int
}

func main() {
    x := 16
    var i Calc
    a := calculator.Add{}
    i = a
    i.First(x)
    i.Second(x)
}
```

I currently have everything organized as:

```
github.com/
   mytestproj/
      calculator/
         addition.go
         addition_test.go
         subtraction.go
         subtraction_test.go
   main/
      main.go
```

In addition.go I have:

```
package calculator

type Add struct{}

func BasicAddition(x int) int {  // this won't be in the final release
    return x + 2
}

func (h Add) First(x int) int {
    x += 5
    return x
}

func (h Add) Second(x int) int {
    x += 10
    return x
}
```

And in addition_test.go I have:

```
package calculator

import "testing"

func TestBasicAddition(t *testing.T) {
    x := 30
    if y := BasicAddition(x); y != 32 {
        t.Errorf("Mine is %v", y)
    }
}

func TestFirst(t *testing.T) {
    x := 10
    if y := First(x); y != 15 {
        t.Errorf("First is %v", y)
    }
}
```

When I run my test I get an error:

```
# github.com/mytestproj/calculator
./addition_test.go:15: undefined: First
FAIL    github.com/mytestproj/calculator [build failed]
```

My question: **How do I test "First?"**

If I remove the test for First completely then the tests run fine and it passes.

Secondary question: The idea is to build a calculator app with many different functions. If there's a better way to organize the code then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`First` is a method on type `Add`. For example,

```
a := Add{}
a.First(x)
```

`addition.go`

```
package calculator

type Add struct{}

func BasicAddition(x int) int { // this won't be in the final release
    return x + 2
}

func (h Add) First(x int) int {
    x += 5
    return x
}

func (h Add) Second(x int) int {
    x += 10
    return x
}
```

`addition_test.go`

```
package calculator

import "testing"

func TestBasicAddition(t *testing.T) {
    x := 30
    if y := BasicAddition(x); y != 32 {
        t.Errorf("Mine is %v", y)
    }
}

func TestFirst(t *testing.T) {
    x := 10
    a := Add{}
    if y := a.First(x); y != 15 {
        t.Errorf("First is %v", y)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -v
=== RUN TestBasicAddition
--- PASS: TestBasicAddition (0.00s)
=== RUN TestFirst
--- PASS: TestFirst (0.00s)
PASS
ok      so/calculator   0.002s
$
```